Rog Strix Scar III (G531GV) - No video signal to external monitor through USB3.1C port (DisplayPort)
As title says, I own a ROG Strix Scar III (G531GV 2019 model) and I want to connect on it two external monitors, first one through the HDMI port with an HDMI to HDMI cable (works without any problems) and second one through USB3.1C port with a USB Type-C to HDMI cable.
This is where the problem appears ... There seems to be no way for windows to identify this monitor through the USB Type-C port. The monitor as well as the USB Type-C to HDMI cable is verified that both work as I can connect another laptop to this monitor with this exact cable..
I've been reading online that not every USB Type-C port provides external monitor connectivity but this doesn't seem to be the case for me as I can see clearly next to the USB Type-C port the D sign (ss 10gb/s D), even laptop's manual states that this port is capable to have an external monitor connected to it on selected models. (Since the D sign exists next to the USB3.1C port, i guess my laptop is one of the selected models..)
Weird thing is that when I plug the cable on both USB Type-C port and the monitor, windows doesn't play the classic sound it does when a device is connected on the computer.. finally, I know that the USB Type-C port is not malfunctioning because I can connect, charge and transfer data between the laptop and my mobile phone without any problems... It seems that only video output is not working for some strange reason.
Any help would be really appreciated as I've got no idea what to do to make my laptop identify and use this external monitor through USB3.1C port...
Thanks in advance.

Did you try to update your laptop to most recent firmware? The 2019 is a little out of date, power delivery was at infant state at that time.
